# Interactive Charts in PDFs

Tags: flash, pdf, actionscript, charts, flash-builder

I have seen quite a few threads close to my query on this website, but still not what I am looking for.
I need to create Interactive charts, and place the same in a PDF. Whatever finding I have done suggest I create a .swf file with all functionality, and simply place that in a PDF. But what is the best resource for creating such a .swf? Should I be looking at Flash or flex?

In terms of interactivity that I want, I want to provide a PDF which has this chart with some predetermined values. And then the user should have the option of changing some values and watching the effect of the same on the chart

Answer (score 0):

I created pdf documents using the jasperesports and iReports, is not difficult, and you have more options. I think that also have option for charts but I never used.

cheer

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking at building something from scratch, hopefully using only libraries in Flash/Flex framework, without using any 3rd party libraries. I am fine even if I can make just a multi-series line chart, forget all different type of fancy charts. Thanks though, will look at these as last resort if I can't get what I am looking for working.

Answer (score 0):

After all the trail and errors, my final choice was flex. It has pretty good libraries. MXML along with AS3 did the job for me